# How do I access special directories in Windows?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, special-folders

What is the C# syntax to retrieve the user's desktop, documents folder and other system folders on Windows?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use [Environment.GetFolderPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.getfolderpath.aspx) with the [Environment.SpecialFolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx) enumeration.  For example:

```
string desktopPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
```

Answer (score 7):

Use:

```
string folder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.*);
```

Where * is one of the enum values.

Answer (score 3):

```
System.Environment.SpecialFolder.MyComputer
```

etc.

Comment: This doesn't actually give you the path - it's an enumeration.  You need to use this with Environment.GetFolderPath to get anything useful...

Comment: You're right, but a glance at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx fills in the rest of the details.

Answer (score 2):

Use [Environment.GetFolderPath Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14tx8hby.aspx)