# System.IO.Directory.Exists always return false in subfolder of system32

Tags: c#, .net, directory, event-log, .net-4.8

I am using .NET Framework 4.8, trying to reach the winevt\Logs folder to get all available Event Logs on the Machine.

Code used is:

```
        const string logDirectory = @"C:\Windows\System32\winevt\Logs";
        if (Directory.Exists(logDirectory)) <-- always false even though directory exists?
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Directory exists");
        }
```

I've tried without "C:", without @ and with "\", with System.IO.Directory.Exists.

I am running as Admin and do not want to setup weird permissions - I guess it is a permissions thing.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Are you compiling this as a 32-bit application? Might have to target `C:\Windows\sysnative\winevt\Logs` or disable file system redirection to make it work

Comment: I always debug these issues with a File Explorer which is easier to find permission issues.  When running in VS you do not automatically get ADMIN privilege's unless you right click the VS shortcut and select RUN AS ADMIN.  This does not apply to a Net application outside VS.

Comment: does this fix the problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3671404/how-do-i-access-special-directories-in-windows

Comment: Shouldn't you just use `System.Diagnostics.EventLog.GetEventLogs()`?